# Security of uploading files to internet?

Tags: security, file-upload, upload, webforms, browser

I have searched high and low for an answer to this question and despite finding a wealth of information relating to server side security for website administrators, I cannot find anything related to client side security, for those uploading the file to the website.

I would like to know what the process is, when a website asks me the location on my hard drive, of a file to upload. For example, if I click on the '*Insert Image*' icon in the Stack Overflow composition box, and then click '*from my computer*', I am presented with a standard file location dialogue where I can choose any file from my hard drive.

This is the same dialogue that you would see on any website where you can upload photos, documents etc. If you are running OS-X and you clicked on 'Insert Image' or 'Attach File' you would trigger the file location dialogue of your operating system, and then be able to navigate to the file.

So, in layman's terms, what is involved in this process, how secure is the process, what prevents the website from navigating to and uploading files that I have not selected, what prevents the website from scanning my computer for password files etc, and can the website learn anything about my computer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In regard to what prevents: **Nothing**. It's all about trust, you trust your **browser** that, no not selected files will be uploaded to server, or the website won't be able to select which files to upload. Your **browser** uploads files. And that's all there is.

Other thing is lunching third party controls like Java applets for file uploading, if you decide to launch them, then you trusted the publisher and he can do whatever he wants with your files.

Comment: It is important to note that this issue is with the **browser**. The web site requests that the browser may open a file picker dialog. The browser does the opening and picking. And of course, the addons to your browser can interfere with your upload as well.

Comment: Edited to emphesize the browser part :)

Comment: Thanks Jonny, your answer helped. I wish there was more information on this process somewhere online. Google does not seem to be able to find anything...

Comment: That's because there is no reason to discuss it. Your question does not touch the subject of security (except for [this scenario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-browser)). What you want to read about is trust. Every once in a while there is an effort to [address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083(v=vs.95)) this issue, but there are no good solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The browser prevents the website from accessing files you don't select. It's only as secure as your browser.

Plugins like java, activeX and flash provide additional vulnerabilities that make your browser less secure.